# Oceanographic model output timeformat to sensible format using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need help with this.

I have oceanographic model output time that is as follows
I have the first index corresponding to 03:00 of Aug 1st 2015 till Nov 30th 2015(total time is a 952x1 size where its a 3 hourly record)

The structure that was given to me is as

```
timeCounter = 

    time_origin: 'seconds since 1950-01-01 00:00:00'
        timeSec: [952x1 double]
```

I have the variable as some t = timeCounter.timeSec that is a 952x1 array.
The problem is when I use datestr(t(1:3)) I get the following results

```
datestr(t(1:3))

ans =

31-Aug-7181
27-Mar-7211
20-Oct-7240
```

How do I view the first index as it is the one corresponding to 03:00 Aug 1st 2015 and next index is +3 hours and so on till the Nov 30th so total of (952*3/24 = 119 days).

Kindly help and thanks once again.

Comment: Can you give us the original values of `t(1:3)`?

Comment: >> t(1:3)

ans =

   1.0e+09 *

    2.0699
    2.0699
    2.0699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a datetime object and just add the number of seconds to it.

```
datetime([1950 1 1 00 00 00])

ans = 

   01-Jan-1950 00:00:00
```

by adding the number of seconds directly in matlab (through the time variable that you have already created), you can get normal formatted time.

```
>> datetime([1950 1 1 00 00 00])+seconds(5e8)

ans = 

   05-Nov-1965 00:53:20
```

In your case seconds(5e8) will be replaced by seconds(t(1)) etc.

If you want fancy formatting, you can use the datetime format option along with the format to change what the output looks like.

```
>> datetime([1950 1 1 00 00 00],'Format','MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm')+seconds(5e8)

ans = 

   Nov-05-1965 00:53
```

A full list of datetime formats can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)

Comment: This is the output when I used your solution.

Comment: Dateindex = datetime([1950 1 1 00 00 00]);

Comment: Dateindex = 

   01-Jan-1950 00:00:00

Comment: >> Dateindex+t(1)

ans = 

   >> Dateindex+t(1)

ans = 

   5669131 CE

Comment: Am I doing somethin wrong here..please help..thanks for the earlier reply

Comment: However when I do following I get this -

Comment: Dateindex+seconds(t(1))

ans = 

   05-Aug-2015 03:00:00

Comment: So does that mean first time index of my data starts 5th aug 2015 at 03:00

Comment: for next time index t(2) in similar fashion Im getting 5th-Aug-2015 at 06:00

Comment: Yes. if t(1)  is 2.0699E9 your first date is 2015 August 5th 3 PM. You have to tell matlab that the t(1) is in seconds.  Depending on the timeframe with your time indexes, and if you add in the date formatting in item 3  you can get the date. I have edited my answer for clarity.